# How to generate a dependency graph for an Android build using the Ninja build system?

Tags: android, build, android-source, ninja

I am working on an Android build project that uses the Ninja build system. I want to generate a dependency graph for the build process to help me understand the relationships between the different components of the project and optimize the build process.

I have tried running the ninja -t graph command from the out/soong directory to generate a Graphviz DOT file containing the build graph, but I received an error message:

```
ninja: error: build.ninja:675: unexpected variable 'symlink_outputs'
    symlink_outputs = ${out}
                            ^ near here
```

How to resolve this problem? What is the best way to generate a dependency graph for an Android build using the Ninja build system? Are there any other tools or methods I can use to analyze the build process and generate a comprehensive graph representation of the dependencies?

Thank you for any help or guidance you can provide.